# Could not resolve com.google.guava:guava:31.1.-jre

Tags: google-chrome, guava, serenity-bdd, cucumber-serenity, serenity

I am trying to download the dependency serenity core 4xx version(testImplementation "net.serenity-bdd:serenity-core:4.0.0-beta-1") but its throwing the below error:
could not resolve com.google.guava:guava:31.1-jre
could not resolve com.google.guava:guava:32.1.2-jre

I tried to resolve it by explicitly giving the below dependency:
"com.google.guava:guava:31.1-jre",
but its still throwing the same two errors shown above

Comment: try to find the lib that is using `com.google.guava:guava:32.1.2-jre` then exclude it.

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem with :
Duplicate class com.google.common.annotations.GwtCompatible found in modules jetified-guava-31.1-android (com.google.guava:guava:31.1-android) and jetified-guava-jdk5-17.0 (com.google.guava:guava-jdk5:17.0)

I solve it by adding this in app Gradle :

```
configurations {
        implementation.exclude group: 'com.google.guava', module: 'guava-jdk5'
    }
```